# What's module or package good for 3-d plotting of magnetic field?

Tags: python, python-3.x

following web page, there are two pictures what i want to(first and second pictures)

[image]

[image]

```
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89820/dipolar-magnetic-field-lines-inside-a-cylinder
```

Or like this one

```
http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/dipolar-magnetic-field/
```

But this code is for Mathematica not python.
is there anybody to know the proper python module or package?

Comment: [mayavi](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_magnetic_field_lines.html#magnetic-field-lines-example) looks like one possibility.